# Blender 2.93.2 particles issue

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

When I add hair particle to my object it does not cover the object rather in goes to the center origin. I did try with blender 2.81, it does work fine. Someone help here I want to use blender 2.93.2 or latest version but I am stack here... can someone help how to get the hair on the object?

Comment: Weird, are you sure you only pressed add particle, hair and nothing else? Can you share your file if everything is set to normal?

Comment: I have faced this problem for two days now.. i have uninstalled all versions and I did install blender 2.81a and the hair worked well, then I uninstalled 2.81a and installed 2.93.0 then 2.93.1 then 2.93.2 and the last three gave me same error as above.